# OpenLayers: How to add a layer to the map

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, openlayers

I'm trying to display map of Poland using OpenLayers with an added layer which I previously uploaded to a local geoserver but I do not know how to connect it in the code?

Map of Poland:
https://jsfiddle.net/b2L6qppd/2/

Code from geoserver:

```
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoserver/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format,
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'Geoserver:ino',
          }
        })
      });
      var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoserver/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format, 
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                   tiled: true,
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'Geoserver:ino',
             tilesOrigin: 430624.45999999996 + "," + 519226.4500999991
          }
        })
      });
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:2180',
          units: 'm',
          axisOrientation: 'neu',
          global: false
      });
```

please help

Comment: To generic problem description: what is your server? what is the error? did you verify that request for tile against public server works when you use local server? Good to see jsfiddle but it does not represent issue you are having.

Comment: For example can you see [that tile](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Raster&CRS=EPSG%3A2180&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG%3A2180&STYLES=&BBOX=488649.3498838544%2C342054.5449186973%2C498422.33688153146%2C351827.5319163744) on your local server?

Comment: If we only look at the title, it's simple: `map.addLayer(myLayer);`

Comment: I use software from http://geoserver.org in version 2.12.1. I don't have error. 
I just want to know, how modify that code https://jsfiddle.net/b2L6qppd/2/  
to add a layer from a local geoserver to a working map topo of poland. 
How add a second url from the local geoserver? http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoserver/wms I can see that tile in my server.